# Why is the [Trunk] icon not displayed for my Trunk branch?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

In TFS when I create a new folder strcuture and added  a new folder to the root folder called "Trunk". Other solutions in TFS display a [Trunk] icon beside that folder like this

[image]

BUT my [Trunk] branch just has a [Folder] icon beside it. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS, we can't create branch directly in Solution Explorer. You have to **[convert a folder to a branch.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files)**

[image]

If you have done this and still can't show the branch icon. Double check if you encounter the following situations:

> **Important:**
>
> You cannot nest branches; therefore, you cannot convert any folder to
>   a branch if it either contains a branch or is contained by a branch.
>   For example, the following illustration shows how neither the parent
>   nor the child of the FeatureTeamA branch can be converted to a branch.
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell TFS it's a branch, rather than a folder

right click on the folder you wish to convert, Click 'Branching and Merging', choose convert to branch.
Tfs will now treat the folder as a branch

[image: Context Menu > Convert to branch]

this is from TFS13, I'd assume 15 will be the same